# How to add custom PHP files in Typo3 9 LTS

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

I want to show advanced search page which includes PHP, HTML and CSS code. Its work is to get User inputs and process/execute a query to get results from Oracle DB. There are multiple PHP files which are linked to each other and index.php is root point. All custom files are in a folder named "prod". So the problem is I want to redirect to index.php after User login in Typo3 9 LTS CMS. But do not know how to achieve this. Please help me what is the best and easy way to do this in Typo3 9 LTS version. Is there any extension which can help me. And which files I have to configure to achieve this. I am using Fluid template extension.

Answer (score 0):

As this are individual PHP scripts unrelated to TYPO3 you can consider them external pages to TYPO3. if you want to have a link inside of your installation to that pages use a page with type `Link to External URL`. After FE-login you can forward to this TYPO3 page, which redirects to the external URL.

Be aware that the external script (your script) has no login validation from TYPO3 and that the URL, once known, can be called without a login.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I want to know is this best way to do it, as it is not securing my search page. I want only login user can access search page.

Comment: If you want only logged-in users to access the search-script you need to integrate your script in TYPO3. Or integrate the authentification check of TYPO3 in your script. or use a TYPO3 plugin to access your scripts. I assume that integrating the scripts in TYPO3 (use an extension with FE-plugin)